# Spring - Cannot deserialize result from HTTP invoker remote service

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-remoting

This error occurs when I'm trying to invoke a method available for me through spring's remote service. 
The error is as follows:

```
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Cannot deserialize result from HTTP invoker remote service [remote service address]; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: default.CommonException
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.convertHttpInvokerAccessException(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:192)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.getQueryResult(Unknown Source)
at default.Main.main
```

**What can be the problem caused by?** Results from all other methods get deserialized without a problem.

EDIT: I try to get this result simply by: 
    `Result res = remoteService.getResult(param);`

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException: sds.eco.common.exception.CommonException`, guess that service throws that exception and `remoteService` cannot find this class, maybe some dependency is missing? (Knowing quite little about Spring). Exception then itself might be because wrong params or so

Comment: Thanks, but I am pretty sure that the parameter I pass to getResult is a valid one since it's an object that I receive using remote service.

Comment: The CommonException is my exception, I fixed the error message so that it is more obvious.

Comment: can you invoke this remote method directly (for example if it is REST by HTTP-request) and see what it actually returns ?

Comment: getResult is supposed to return Result object and the method that I use to get parameter object returns some let's say Parameter object.

Comment: yes i can see that but the problem might be that the service returns something that cannot be built to a `Response` object. So it might help if you could log - with some interceptor for example - or make the low level http call - with browser for example -to the service and see the serialized from of response

Answer (score 1):

The remote service has thrown a default.CommonException, which is then serialized  by spring remoting and then tried to deserialized: 
at this point you get the ClassNotFound.

I think you don't have default.CommonException on the classpath on the caller side, so deserializing does not work.